# Is there a node way to detect if a network interface comes online?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have looked at the os module and the ip module but those are really good at telling me the current ip address of the system not if a new one comes online or goes offline. I know I can accomplish this problem using udev rules (I'm on Ubuntu) but I was hoping for a way to do this using only node. How would I go about discovering if a network interface is started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no event bases way to do this in node. The solution we came up with was to use UDEV to generate events when a device goes offline and comes online.

Answer (score 2):

You could always setup a listener using [`process.nextTick`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_arg) and see if the set of interfaces has changed since last time. If so, send out the updates to any listeners.

```
'use strict';

let os = require('os');

// Track the listeners and provide a way of adding a new one
// You would probably want to put this into some kind of module
// so it can be used in various places
let listeners = [];
function onChange(f) {
    if (listeners.indexOf(f) === -1) {
        listeners.push(f);
    }
}

let oldInterfaces = [];
process.nextTick(function checkInterfaces() {
    let interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();

    // Quick and dirty way of checking for differences
    // Not very efficient
    if (JSON.stringify(interfaces) !== JSON.stringify(oldInterfaces)) {
        listeners.forEach((f) => f(interfaces));
        oldInterfaces = interfaces;
    }

    // Continue to check again on the next tick
    process.nextTick(checkInterfaces);
});

// Print out the current interfaces whenever there's a change
onChange(console.log.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can use npm package [network-interfaces-listener](https://www.npmjs.com/package/network-interfaces-listener). It will send data every time an(or all) interface becomes online, or offline. Not a perfect solution, but it will do.

I tried the answer of Mike Cluck. The problem I faced with `nextTick()` approach is that it gets called in the end.

The package creates a separate thread(or worker in `nodejs`). The worker has `setInterval()` which calls the passed callback function after every second. The callback compares previous second data, if it does not match, then change has happened, and it calls listener.

Note(edit): The package mentioned is created by me in order to solve the problem.